# Comparative Query

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a query to compare data from two date ranges.

First Date range:

```
select code,description, quantity*each as Total
from orderiteminfo oi, orderinfo o, invoiceinfo i
where oi.orderid = o.orderid
and o.invoiceid = i.invoiceid
and i.invdate between '2014-01-01' and '2014-02-01'
group by oi.code, description, quantity, each
```

Second Date range:

```
select code,description, quantity*each as Total
from orderiteminfo oi, orderinfo o, invoiceinfo i
where oi.orderid = o.orderid
and o.invoiceid = i.invoiceid
and i.invdate between '2015-01-01' and '2015-02-01'
group by oi.code, description, quantity, each
```

I would want results to be:

Code|Description|Total for First Date Range|Total for second Date Range

Comment: We also might not have the exact same codes in the two date ranges if we have added or removed codes over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
SELECT code,
       description,
       SUM(CASE
             WHEN i.invdate BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-02-01' THEN quantity * each
           END) AS [Total for First Date Range],
       SUM(CASE
             WHEN i.invdate BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-02-01' THEN quantity * each
           END) AS [Total for second Date Range]
FROM   orderiteminfo oi
       INNER JOIN orderinfo o
               ON oi.orderid = o.orderid
       INNER JOIN invoiceinfo i
               ON o.invoiceid = i.invoiceid
WHERE  ( i.invdate BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-02-01'
          OR i.invdate BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-02-01' )
GROUP  BY oi.code,
          description
```

As a side note always use `Inner Join` syntax for joining two tables instead of old style comma separated join and keep the filters alone in `Where` clause which is more readable

Comment: So I missed something in my original query I need to show a SUM(quantity * Each) for each oi.code.    How would I modify the query for this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, I think you could rather do this in a single query using `case when` statement:

```
select code,
       description, 
       case 
          when i.invdate between '2014-01-01' and '2014-02-01'
            then quantity*each 
        end  Total_for_First_Date_Range,
        case 
          when i.invdate between '2015-01-01' and '2015-02-01'
            then quantity*each 
        end  Total_for_Second_Date_Range              
from orderiteminfo oi, orderinfo o, invoiceinfo i
where oi.orderid = o.orderid
and o.invoiceid = i.invoiceid 
group by oi.code, description, quantity, each; --not sure if you need this
```